# Trying To Prevent Repost Data on refresh

Tags: sql-server, forms, asp-classic

working with pre existing code just a simple patch i added ontop

```
//first get the variables
bridge = namef & valuef
//a paranoid double check
if session("gap") = session("oldgap") then session("gap") = "null"
//the actual comparison
if bridge = session("gap") then
 drawbridge = ""
else
 drawbridge = inputscrubber("action")
end if
session("oldgap") = session ("gap")
session("gap") = namef & valuef
```

Comment: they need to stay on the same page and continue posting NEW data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to avoid such issues.

The idea is that once the form is posted, you process it and redirect to a *different* page. The user at this point can refresh without any issue.

Comment: its not advisable for me to rewrite the data function, like i said im patching another persons code, also they are supposed to stay on the same page

Comment: @ert3 - I am not talking about the data function. It is what you do _after_ it. Redirect instead of reloading the same page.